# Airflow tasks not running in correct order?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

`cleanup_pbp` is downstream of all 4 of `load_pbp_30629, load_pbp_30630, load_to_bq_30629, load_to_bq_30630`. `cleanup_pbp` started at 2021-12-05T08:54:48.

[image]

however, `load_pbp_30630`, one of the 4 upstream tasks, did not end until 2021-12-05T09:02:23.

[image]

How is `cleanup_pbp` running before `load_pbp_30630` ends? I've never seen this before. I know our task dependencies have a bit of criss-cross going on, but that shouldn't explain why the tasks run out of order?

Comment: Is there a trigger rule set on the `cleanup_pbp` task?

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same problem and after checking, finally we found out that the problem is caused by the **loop** function in Dag script.

Actually we use a for loop to create tasks as well as their relationships. As in each iteration it will create the upstream task and the downstream task (like the `cleanup_pbp` in your case) and always give the same id to downstream one and define its relations (ex. `Load_pbp_xxx >> cleanup_pbp`), in graph or tree view it considers this downstream id has serval dependences but when Dag runs it takes only the relation defined in the last iteration. If you check Task Instance you will see only one task in its upstream_list.

The solution is to move the definition of this final task out of the loop but keep the definition of dependencies inside the loop. This well resolves our problem of running order, the final task won’t start until all dependences are finished. (with tigger rule `all_success` of course)

I’m not sure if you are in the same situation as us but hope this will give you some idea.